# Blueimp jQuery-File-Upload with codeigniter upload and rename and resize the images

Tags: php, codeigniter, blueimp, multifile-uploader

I have been searching and trying for many and many days , I am using

[Blueimp jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

for multiple file upload with codeigniter  , I have Questions about some aspects of using it :

1. How can I rename the uploaded file with serial like `15_1.jpg /
   15_2.jpg / 15_3.jpg`
2. How to use the same form to submit twice first submit  for
   uploading , and second submit  for insert some inputs to database.
3. How to resize images before uploading

Comment: Please keep 1 question per question and don't ask broad questions.

Comment: @Alex well, they related to the same subject and i can't separate it in another question

Comment: that right there is a good indication that your "question" is too broad. and although they might be related - that doesn't mean that you can't make an attempt in steps and ask questions along the way.

Answer (score 1):

1)For renaming
Instead of

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

do this,

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename);
```

will product a random number based on the current time and append the extension from the originally uploaded file.

2) for uploading and inserting using same form, you'll need two buttons

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
                .appendTo(document.body)
                .click(function () {
                    data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                    data.submit();
                });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
        }
    });
});
```

similarly for inserting create another function and call it..

3)Resize image before uploading?.. they give you 
to do client-side image resizing you need to include the following scripts:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
```

Then, all you need to do is to set the option disableImageResize to false.
By default, images are resized to FullHD (1920x1080), but you can define your own Options:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
    dataType: 'json',
    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
        .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
    imageMaxWidth: 800,
    imageMaxHeight: 800,
    imageCrop: true // Force cropped images
})
```